# Using fs.readdir and fs.statSync returns ENOENT, no such file or directory error

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

This works:

```
    var promise = new Future(),
        dirs = [],
        stat;
        

    Fs.readdir(Root + p, function(error, files){
        _.each(files, function(file) {
            //stat = Fs.statSync(file);
            //if ( stat.isDirectory() ) {
                dirs.push(file);
            //}
        });

        promise.return(dirs);
    });
```

This does not:

```
    var promise = new Future(),
        dirs = [],
        stat;
        

    Fs.readdir(Root + p, function(error, files){
        _.each(files, function(file) {
            stat = Fs.statSync(file);
            if ( stat.isDirectory() ) {
                dirs.push(file);
            }
        });

        promise.return(dirs);
    });
```

Resulting in "Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'fonts'", but "fonts" is the first directory in the tree, and it does exist.

I've got to be missing something silly. I'm trying to return folder/directory names only.

While I'm at it, does anyone know how to return all levels of directories?

For example, the result could be:

```
[
    "fonts",
    "fonts/font-awesome",
    "images",
    "images/somepath",
    "images/somepath/anotherpath"
]
```

That is my next goal, after figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readdir` will give you the names of the entries in the folder, not the whole path. This will work:

```
stat = Fs.statSync(Root + p + "/" + file);
```

The whole code:

```
var promise = new Future(),
    dirs = [],
    stat,
    fullPath;


Fs.readdir(Root + p, function(error, files){
    _.each(files, function(file) {
        fullPath = Root + p + "/" + file;
        stat = Fs.statSync(fullPath);
        if ( stat.isDirectory() ) {
            dirs.push(fullPath);
        }
    });

    promise.return(dirs);
});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Will accept answer as soon as it allows me. Thank you so much. You wouldn't happen to know how to pull off the last part of my question would you? Retrieving all levels of directories?

Comment: That is a bit more difficult. You should use recursive algorithms to do this. Each time you encounter a directory, you call the lister again using the new path. The lister returns a promise that will be resolved with the data it got. You resolve the promise when every other promise you got gets resolved.