# Node server returns request only after I refresh the page

Tags: json, node.js, express

Firstly, this is my first Node app, so I'm sorry if the question is stupid.
So, the thing is that I try to send JSON data after visiting the specified route.
My code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var objFromFolder = require('./objFromFolder');
var app = express();
var initialTree;
var currentTree;

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '../../views')
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use("/frontend", express.static(__dirname + '/../frontend'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.json(JSON.stringify(initialTree));
});

app.get('/:folderName', function (req, res) {
  var validPath = path.resolve(__dirname + '../../', req.params.folderName);
  objFromFolder(validPath, function(err, folderItems) {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    currentTree = folderItems.sort(function (item) {
      return !(item.isFolder);
    });
  });
  res.send(JSON.stringify(currentTree));
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  objFromFolder(__dirname + '../../', function(err, folderItems) {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    initialTree = folderItems.sort(function (item) {
      return !(item.isFolder);
    });
  });
  console.log('Ready on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

`objFromFolder` module code:

```
var objFromFolder = (function () {
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');

  var objFromFolder = function (root, returnItems) {
    var folderItems = [];

    fs.readdir(root, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      var pending = files.length;

      files.forEach(function (file) {
        var filePath = path.resolve(root, file);
        var fileAsObj = {
          path: filePath,
          name: file
        };

        fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stats) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
            return;
          }

          if (stats && stats.isFile()) {
            fileAsObj.isFolder = false;
          }

          if (stats && stats.isDirectory()) {
            fileAsObj.isFolder = true;
          }

          folderItems.push(fileAsObj);
          if (!--pending) {
            returnItems(null, folderItems);
          }
        });
      });
    });

  }

  return objFromFolder;
})();

module.exports = objFromFolder;
```

Task of this app is to return working directory structure as a list of objects. So, for example, when I visit `localhost:8080/node_modules`, first time I see just blank page, but after I refresh the page, the server returns JSON. When I visit the `/` route, JSON is returned and I do not need to refresh the page.

P.S. I removed error checking from `objFromFolder` module, instead of that I just `return` from the function if `files` variable is undefined. Now `/` route works fine again, but other routes are always in loading.

Answer (score 0):

Your `objFromFolder` function does some asynchronous work (read from file, etc.). So when you send the respsonse to your `/:folderName` request, the folder tree is not ready yet (the async job didn't finish).
So you have to put your `res.send(...)` in your callback function like :

```
app.get('/:folderName', function (req, res) {
  var validPath = path.resolve(__dirname + '../../', req.params.folderName);
  objFromFolder(validPath, function(err, folderItems) {

    if (err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
      throw err;
    }

    currentTree = folderItems.sort(function (item) {
      return !(item.isFolder);
    });

    // here the tree is ready
    res.send(JSON.stringify(currentTree));
  });

  // here the function code above might not have executed yet
});
```

**Edit**

I tested your app and when I requested `/node_modules` there was a wrong path requested. So I had to put:

```
var validPath = path.resolve(__dirname, req.params.folderName);
```

because my `node_modules` folder is at the root of my project (same as `app.js`) so `__dirname` has the correct path.

Comment: Now I get an error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'E:\Projects\File-System\favicon.ico'`

Comment: don't know if it's related.. you should check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853563/error-enoent-open-favicon-ico)

Comment: After I restart the server without changing a route JSON was returned, but server fell down because of the same error.

Comment: I updated my answer with `console.error(err.stack);`  I think there is a problem with the `objFromFolder` code. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265270/using-fs-readdir-and-fs-statsync-returns-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error) could help

Comment: `console.error(err.stack);` just shows the same error :(

Comment: @VyacheslavPalamar ENOENT means the file doesn't exist.  The problem is that your browser sends a request for the favicon, and your server doesn't like that.

Comment: @AaronDufour but why there is no such error when I visit the default route?

Comment: @VyacheslavPalamar I updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: In my project `app.js` is in the `server` folder. I moved `app.js` and `objFromFolder.js` from `server` folder to root of the project, but the error is the same.

Comment: @VyacheslavPalamar did you change the line like the edit in my response ?

Comment: I even added `faviocin.ico` to my projects but Node still says `ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'E:\Projects\File-System\favicon.ico'`, not `ENOENT`

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the folder you want to scan exists. 
You can install a [path-exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-exists) npm module and wrap your function to the check of path-exists.

```
var objFromFolder = (function() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var pathExists = require('path-exists');

    var objFromFolder = function(root, returnItems) {
        var folderItems = [];

        // Check the path exist
        if (pathExists.sync(root)) {
            fs.readdir(root, function(err, files) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                var pending = files.length;

                files.forEach(function(file) {
                    var filePath = path.resolve(root, file);
                    var fileAsObj = {
                        path: filePath,
                        name: file
                    };

                    fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }

                        if (stats && stats.isFile()) {
                            fileAsObj.isFolder = false;
                        }

                        if (stats && stats.isDirectory()) {
                            fileAsObj.isFolder = true;
                        }

                        folderItems.push(fileAsObj);
                        if (!--pending) {
                            returnItems(null, folderItems);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }

    }

    return objFromFolder;
})();

module.exports = objFromFolder;
```

I have also modified your app, is better to wrap the code inside the app.get to a single function or move the sort inside your module.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var objFromFolder = require('./objFromFolder');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '../../views')
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use("/frontend", express.static(__dirname + '/../frontend'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  var validPath =  path.join(__dirname, '../../');

  objFromFolder(validPath, function(err, folderItems) {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    var currentTree = folderItems.sort(function (item) {
      return !(item.isFolder);
    });

    res.send(JSON.stringify(currentTree));
  });

});

app.get('/:folderName', function (req, res) {
  var validPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../', req.params.folderName);

  objFromFolder(validPath, function(err, folderItems) {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    var currentTree = folderItems.sort(function (item) {
      return !(item.isFolder);
    });

    res.send(JSON.stringify(currentTree));
  });

});




var port = app.get('port');

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Ready on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: I have the task to implement it without any third-party modules.
Thank you for your advice about code.